# Amazon S3 UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD for X-Amz-Content-Sha256 Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I am using TypeScript and Next.js 14 and my s3 bucket is working perfectly in localhost but not in production. I did create a separate bucket with policy and IAM user for production as well. All the keys match up, but I am receiving an error of CORS and a 403 forbidden error as well in production.

I am getting this error when i call the deleteAudio function in the server code:
SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Inside the payload for the errors I am receiving an UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD for the X-Amz-Content-Sha256. However, in localhost it is working with the UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD.

[image]

[image]

The error is happening on the handleAudioUploadtoS3 function
Here is my client side code:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { Textarea } from "@/components/ui/textarea";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Montserrat } from "next/font/google";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useProModal } from "@/hooks/use-pro-modal";
import { Download } from "lucide-react";
import { ImSpinner3 } from "react-icons/im";
import { getSignedURL } from "@/app/_actions/actions";
import { MAX_CHARACTERS } from "@/constants";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";

const montserrat = Montserrat({
  weight: "600",
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

export default function YourVoicesPage({
  params,
}: {
  params: { id: string; image: string; name: string; flag: string };
}) {
  const sourceElem = useRef(null);
  const router = useRouter();
  const proModal = useProModal();
  const [voice, setVoice] = useState("");
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<Blob | "">("");
  const [converting, setConverting] = useState(false);
  const [characterCount, setCharacterCount] = useState(0);

  // console.log("params", params);
  // using the params to get the correct name, image and flag
  const nameString = params.id[1].split("%26")[1];
  const name = nameString.split("%3D")[1];
  const imageString = params.id[1].split("%26")[0];
  const correctImagePath = imageString.startsWith("/")
    ? imageString
    : `/${imageString}`;
  console.log("image", correctImagePath);
  const flagString = params.id[2];
  const correctFlagPath = flagString.startsWith("/")
    ? flagString
    : `/${flagString}`;

  console.log("flag", correctFlagPath);

  // using the params to get the correct voiceID
  const voiceIDString = params.id[0];
  const voiceID = voiceIDString.replace("%26image%3D", "");

  const handleTextChange = (e: any) => {
    const newText = e.target.value;
    setCharacterCount(newText.length);
    setVoice(newText); // Update the state with the new text
  };

  const isGenerateDisabled = characterCount > MAX_CHARACTERS;

  // Upload and save Audio to S3 bucket & database
  const handleAudioUploadtoS3 = async (audioBlob: Blob) => {
    console.log("audioBlob", audioBlob);

    const signedURLResult = await getSignedURL({ name, correctImagePath, text:voice });
    console.log("signedURL", signedURLResult);
    if (!signedURLResult.success) {
      console.log("error", signedURLResult.error);
      return;
    }
    const url = signedURLResult.success.url;
    console.log("url", url);

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: audioBlob,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg",
      },
    });

    if(!response.ok) {
      console.log("error", response);
      return;
    }
    
    if(response.ok) {
       toast.success("Audio file saved to your dashboard");
    }

    console.log("response", response);

  };

  // Create the audio from the user's input text
  const handleVoiceInput = async () => {
    try {
      setConverting(true);
      const response = await fetch("/api/voice-creation", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          voiceID: voiceID,
          text: voice,
          characterCount: characterCount,
        }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status === 403) {
          setConverting(false);
          proModal.onOpen();
        } else {
          console.log("Unexpected response status:", response.status);
        }
        return; // Stop further processing
      }

      const blobResponse = await response.blob();
      setResponse(blobResponse);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("error", error);
      if (error?.response?.status === 403) {
        proModal.onOpen();
      }
    } finally {
      setConverting(false);
      router.refresh();
    }
  };

  // console.log("voiceID", voiceID);
  return (
    <div className="flex w-full h-screen bg-slate-100">
      <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto flex flex-col">
        <h1
          className={cn(
            "mt-10 font-bold text-center text-4xl mb-10",
            montserrat.className
          )}
        >
          Your Voices
        </h1>
        <div className="flex flex-col mb-8">
          <Image src={correctImagePath} alt="name" width={250} height={250} />
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 mx-auto mb-6 items-center">
            <h3 className="font-semibold text-2xl">{name}</h3>
            <Image src={correctFlagPath} alt="flag" width={50} height={50} />
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
            <Textarea
              className=""
              value={voice}
              onChange={handleTextChange}
              placeholder="Type your text here..."
            />
            <p className={voice.length > 200 ? "text-red-500" : ""}>
              {/* Character Count: {voice.length}/200 */}
              Character Count: {characterCount}
            </p>
            <Button disabled={isGenerateDisabled} onClick={handleVoiceInput}>
              Generate
              {converting && (
                <span className="animate-spin text-lg ml-3">
                  <ImSpinner3 />
                </span>
              )}
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        {response && (
          <>
            <audio
              src={response ? URL.createObjectURL(response) : ""}
              controls
            />
            {/* <source ref={sourceElem} src={response} type="audio/mpeg" /> */}
            <div className="flex flex-row gap-6 items-center mt-10">
                 <a
              className="flex items-center gap-4"
              href={response ? URL.createObjectURL(response) : ""}
              download
            >
              {response ? (
                <div className="flex gap-6 items-center">
                  <Button className="flex gap-5">
                    <Download size={16} className="text-white" />{" "}
                    <p className="text-white">Download Audio File</p>
                  </Button>
                </div>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </a> 
            <Button variant={'outline'}
              onClick={() => handleAudioUploadtoS3(response)}
            >
              Save to Your Dashboard
            </Button>
            </div>
         
           
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my server code:

```
"use server";

import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/utils/authOptions";
import {
  S3Client,
  PutObjectCommand,
  DeleteObjectCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION!,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
  },
});

export async function getSignedURL({
  name,
  correctImagePath,
  text
}: {
  name: string;
  correctImagePath: string;
  text: string
}) {
  // Get the user's session
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  if (!session) return { error: "Not authenticated" };
  console.log("testing out", name, correctImagePath);

  const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
  const key = `users/${session.user.id}/audio/${timestamp}_audioFile.mp3`;

  const putObjctCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
    Key: key,
    Metadata: {
      userId: session.user.id,
      name: name,
      image: correctImagePath,
    },
  });

  const signedURL = await getSignedUrl(s3, putObjctCommand, {
    expiresIn: 60,
  });

  const newAudio = await prismadb.audioFile.create({
    data: {
      userId: session.user.id,
      url: signedURL.split("?")[0],
      fileName: `${timestamp}_audioFile.mp3`,
      image: correctImagePath,
      aiName: name,
      text: text
    },
  });

  console.log("newAudio", newAudio)

  return { success: { url: signedURL, audio: newAudio } };
}

export async function deleteAudio({ audioId }: { audioId: string }) {
  // Get the user's session
  console.log("testing out", audioId);
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  if (!session) return { error: "Not authenticated" };

  const audio = await prismadb.audioFile.findUnique({
    where: { id: audioId },
  });

  console.log("audio", audio);

  if (!audio) return { error: "Audio file not found" };

  if (audio.userId !== session.user.id) {
    return { error: "You do not have permission to delete this audio file" };
  }

  // delete from s3
  const deleteObjctCommand = new DeleteObjectCommand({
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
    Key: `users/${session.user.id}/audio/${audio.fileName}`,
  });

  await s3.send(deleteObjctCommand);

  await prismadb.audioFile.delete({
    where: { id: audioId },
  });

  return { success: "Audio file deleted" };
}
```

If you think you need more information to help me solve this that would be appreciated.